# Custom icon using pyinstaller is not working

Tags: python, icons, custom-controls, exe, pyinstaller

I used below command to get a custom icon for my .exe file but my custom icon doesnt appear on my exe file even after successful completion of the command :

> pyinstaller --noconsole --onefile
>   --icon="C:\Users\anubhav.jhalani\Desktop\index.ico" run.py

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Sometimes Windows can't generate a new thumbnail, try to move your executable into another folder and check if it shows the new icon file.